# Active Report 6 page footer is not growing

Tags: activereports

We are using Active Report 6 version for reporting purpose. We have a case where we need to display few number of rows in the page footer. These rows are dynamimc i.e. sometimes it would be 3 or 6 or any number.
I have searched a lot and on one URL (http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/35718/PrintPost.aspx) it is mentioned that Page Header & Page Footer are not allowed to grow in Active Report.

I have also tried to re-size the Page footer height on the "Before_Print" event of "PageFooter". Still, no luck!

Is there any provision by which I can dynamically re-size the Page Footer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ReportStart event to run a separate query to determine how many rows you need and resize the PageHeader/Footer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

PageFooter and PageHeader are fixed size on the page once the page has been created because their size determines the remaining area for content.   The only way to modify it on a per page basis is in PageStart event.   So at the start of each page, you can check how many records you need to print on that page and change the size of the page footer section.   there are no other options.